# Cycle where i append variables to the end of widget names

Tags: c++, qt, widget, qtwidgets

For my app im creating i need to display values in three separate table widgets. I have currently three tables named like this:

```
    //tableWidget_line_1
    //tableWidget_line_2
    //tableWidget_line_3
```

I would like to create a for cycle that would assign numbers of rows like this, and later perform other operations with them.

Idea i've tried was:

```
for(int k=0;k<3;k++){
ui->tableWidget_line_[k]->setRowCount(k);
}
```

so the first tablewidget would have one line, second two, third three...

Tried this naming technique

```
ui->tableWidget_line_'"+[k]"'->setRowCount(k);
and
ui->tableWidget_line_"+[k]"->setRowCount(k);
```

but to no avail.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated since. I realise this might not be solvable since i havent yet ran into anyone having this issue, but maybe someone will know.

Thanks!

Comment: Names cannot be concatenated from other things. Simply use an array instead of variables with names `_1`, `_2`,...

Comment: Also, don't ask identical question when your question is closed. Improve it and it will be reopened.

Comment: Old question [Assigning values for widget with same base names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78146682/assigning-values-for-widget-with-same-base-names)